# How to run android app in real device from ubuntu 12.04 OS?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, driver

I cant able to find the drivers of my android tab earlier I was using a PC suite in windows 8 to run android app directly in my real device from eclipse.

I recently switch to ubuntu 12.04 ,Tell me how to install drivers of my device, and also is there any PC suite or android phone management tool in ubuntu likewise in windows which automatically install all drivers and control your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device should be able to work without any aditional drivers. Just follow the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) on the topic. (Assuming you have already installed adb), and pay close attention to step 3 of **Setting up a Device for Development** where you have to create a udev rule for the device.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you solve your problem:

- Figure out the venderId for your device and save it somewhere.
- Now, inside ~/.android/ folder, open the file called **adb_usb.ini** and add your venderId below the last line like this: **0x2207** with the last 4 digits being the vender ID of your device.
- Then, if 51-android.rules does not exist inside **/etc/udev/rules.d/**, create one and place all your rules in it. You can easily find the rules through the link in the above answer.
- Once you have completed these steps, you should be able to restart/reload your rules and ready to start using your tools.

Good luck!

Comment: What if I cant able to find my vendors ID , My brands Id is not listed there                                       http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds

Comment: Without your device connected, run the command `lsusb`. Then connect your device and run the command again. The newly added line in the output will be the one for your device. The field formatted like xxxx:yyyy after 'ID' is the vendor ID (xxxx) and product ID (yyyy).