# How to run apps in real phone instead of emulator.?

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, adb

Hi all i'm using adt in ubuntu 12.04. I want to test & run my android application directly in a real phone instead of running in an emulator. I searched many but din't get how to do this in ubuntu. if anybody know how to install or any blogs or any website please share.

Thanking you all.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756451/how-to-install-an-apk-file-on-an-android-phone

Comment: When I plug in my phone it automatically shows up in Eclipse when I click run as Android Application... I find it more difficult to get the emulator going... under Developer Options in your phone you have to make sure USB Debugging is checked.

Comment: answer: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: possible to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425806/how-to-run-android-app-in-real-device-from-ubuntu-12-04-os

Comment: @CodeCamper i checked USB Debugging but still my device is not detecting in my eclipse

Comment: i'm using ubuntu, do i change anything in ubuntu..?
my phone is micromax a240 running android 4.2.1

Comment: @dharshan are you able to connect to your phone with adb?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled USB debugging?
Connect it with USB debugging on and,Eclipse'll detect it.
Hope it'll help.

Comment: eclipse is not detecting my device. i installed genymotion for running my apps. i tried by closing genymotion also but eclipse throwing no compatible device found error. 

i checked USB debugging in my phone's developers option

Answer (score 0):

On your android device:  Applications > Development > USB Debugging
Then just plug in the phone to the USB. Now apps will run on your device instead of emulator.

Comment: i checked USB debugging but still not detecting.
i'm using ubuntu as my OS and my device is micromax a240 running android 4.2.1